# Which keyboard shortcuts allow for scroll up and down in the Windows Subsystem for Linux terminal emulator?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

`Shift + PageUp` and `Shift + PageDown`are the normal Ubuntu shortcut keys for scrolling up and down without the mouse in the terminal emulator. It doesn't seem to work in Windows Subsystem for Linux for me (Windows 10 1607, Lenovo Carbon X1 2015).

Has anyone figured out a workaround or know if this feature is on its way? I see some discussion here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/279

Comment: Such features depend on the (Windows) terminal emulator. Having the Linux subsystem doesn't change the functionality of the emulator where it runs.

Comment: Thanks! The `Ctrl + Up` and `Ctrl + Down` shortcut keys work on cmd, but don't on the bash.exe program that runs the Windows Subsystem for Linux. Realized they are documenting bugs and such at https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/. Whatever the bash.exe program is (*is* it a terminal emulator?), it doesn't support either `Shift + Page Up` or `Ctrl + Up` keyboard navigation shortcuts. Will ask over there!